# PowerBI filter- selected Date between Start and End date

Tags: powerbi

I'm building a PowerBI report from a dataset that contains start and end dates. I'd like to filter the dataset based on rows that would encompass a selected date in another table.

The screenshot here shows a sample. I want to click a date in the table on the right and have the table on the left filtered where the selected date is between the start & end date.

[image: Two datasets side-by-side. One has a Start and End date. The other is a list of dates.]

I've attempted several different things using columns and measures, but I haven't been able to nail it down. I also attempted to create a new table from a DAX expression that references the selected date, but that caused errors.

How can I dynamically filter the dataset based on the selected date being between the start and end date values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure to check whether a row overlaps the selected date range:

```
Date Included = 
IF (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( Table1[Start Date], 1 ) <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) &&
    FIRSTNONBLANK( Table1[End Date], 1 ) >= MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    "Include",
    "Exclude"
)
```

Add this Measure as a filter on your visualisation, where `Date Included` is `Include`

Now you can filter your Calendar table ( to single value, or range), and only overlapping rows from your fact table will be displayed.

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55925954/ for worked example PBIX file

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately something isn't quite right in my report. The measure seems to have the same value for every row in the table. If the Date isn't filtered, it's "Include" but as soon as I filter it changes to "Exclude" on every record. What might make it have the same value on every record?

Comment: Do you have a relationship between your tables? Did you look at the example PBIX file?

Comment: I did look at it, and I haven't been able to figure out what you did differently from me. Here's a screenshot showing the new column added, with all having the same (incorrect) value: https://imgur.com/a/XT3uckg And no, no relationship between the tables.

Comment: I figured it out, and boy this one is embarassing. When I created the measure, I refered to the start and end date in a different table. After fixing those references, it works brilliantly. Thank you!