# PowerBI how to use one slicer with two columns (dates)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have a table with columns 'date from' and 'date to', and visualize them as bars using asTimeline visual.

I want to add a slicer which will work on both of these fields simultaneously. Currently I have two slicers working independently on each of those fields:

[image]

This is not really intuitive. Since start and end both define a period in time, if the period is inside the slider selection, it should be included. But slicers work on only one field. So I probably need to perform some DAX magic to create a field based on those two, but I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

First create an measure to check a row overlaps the your date range:

```
Date Included = 
IF (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( DateTable[Start Date], 1 ) <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) &&
    FIRSTNONBLANK( DateTable[End Date], 1 ) >= MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    "Include",
    "Exclude"
)
```

and , add above Measure as a filter on your visualisation, where **Date Included** is **Include**

Than you can filter your Calendar table to single value, or range.

Also,only overlapping rows from your fact table will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by using a separate calendar-table and a measure: [PowerBI filter- selected Date between Start and End date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925954/powerbi-filter-selected-date-between-start-and-end-date)

Another way to solve this, and keep using the two slicers more intuitively, is described here: https://radacad.com/from-and-to-date-slicers-in-power-bi-filtering-based-on-two-fields. The solution describes how to set the properties of those timeline-slicers so that it makes a bit more sense for the user (set the "Start of employment" slicer as Type - After and the "End of employment" as Type - Before).